# concatenating data frames with difftime columns in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data frames with exactly the same columns and I'm trying to concatenate them together using dplyr::union.

```
union(df.3, df.4)
```

However, I get the error:

> Error: cannot join on columns 'run.time' x 'run.time': Can't join on > 'run.time' x 'run.time' because of incompatible types (difftime / difftime)

Being that the `run.time` columns are the same type, why am I getting this error?

```
 class(df.4$run.time)
[1] "difftime"
> class(df.3$run.time)
[1] "difftime"
>
```

I know I can just use `rbind` to do the concatenation, but I was curious why `union` doesn't work.

Comment: Check [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/src/dplyr.cpp)  for the underlying `C++` code. Interestingly, `dplyr:::compatible_data_frame(df.3, df.4)` returns `TRUE`.

Comment: Provide a minimal reproducible example so others can test their ideas.

Comment: I'd recommend filing an minimal reprex on the dplyr github issues page

Answer (score 2):

I feel the need to warn you about this:

> I know I can just use rbind to do the concatenation

I would be *very* cautious about using `rbind` when one of your columns is a `difftime`.  Consider this example:

```
now <- Sys.time()
foo <- data.frame(X = now+10 - now)
bar <- data.frame(X = now+120 - now)

foo
##          X
## 1  10 secs

bar
##          X
## 1   2 mins

rbind(foo, bar)
##          X
## 1  10 secs
## 2   2 secs   !!!

rbind(bar, foo)
##          X
## 1   2 mins
## 2  10 mins   !!!
```

Comment: That's a rather significant problem!