# Can't use dplyr joins on two date columns

Tags: r

I'm encountering an error where I try to join two data frames using the dplyr join functions by two Date columns. This is the error I get:

```
Error: cannot join on columns 'DateInfo' x 'DateInfo': Can't join on 'DateInfo' x 'DateInfo' because of incompatible types (Date / Date)
```

The base `merge` function works fine and I can't seem to find an example of what could be causing this through googling or other stack overflow questions.

The problem is I can't create a reproducible example and the data I am using I can't share. For example this works with no problems:

```
d1 <- data_frame(Num = 1:5, DateInfo = as.Date(c("2014-01-03", "2014-04-05", "2015-01-03", "2014-04-02", "2011-07-28"), format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
d2 <- data_frame(Name = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), DateInfo = as.Date(c("2014-01-03", "2014-04-05", "2015-01-03", "2014-04-02", "2011-07-28"), format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
d3 <- left_join(d1, d2, by = c("DateInfo" = "DateInfo"))
```

Has anyone had any experience with not being able to join on two columns that are, as far as the `class` function is concerned, are the same type but still getting this error?

EDIT: Just to get this out of the way I can get around this error by using merge or converting the dates to characters and then joining, so I'm really just interested in why `dplyr` would tell me I can't merge on two columns with the same type.

Comment: what class is it? I don't think `dplyr` and `data.table` support POSIXlt

Comment: Of course I would find another example after I posted this. [This person](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28699035/concatenating-data-frames-with-difftime-columns-in-dplyr) saw a similar error. Looks like the last resolution was Hadley suggesting him submit an issue through github. I'll see if I can find that issue.

Comment: @scribbles they are both "Date" classes in the same format as the `d1` and `d2` data frames in my example.

Comment: I found [this issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1303) which I actually think is related to my bug. Apparently the "Date" format for data pulled from a MySql DB is stored as an integer while the `as.Date` function in r stores them as numeric, so you are unable to merge them. Some of my data was originally pulled from a postgresql DB so that may be what is the problem here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason I can't merge is how the two Date objects are stored. Thanks to [this issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1303) I decided to check the structure of how the two objects are stored and sure enough one is stored as an integer and one is stored as a numeric:

```
> dput(df1$DateInfo[1])
structure(16373, class = "Date")
> dput(df2$DateInfo[1])
structure(16372L, class = "Date")
```

It appears that the data that was pulled form a DB through the dplyr sql functions is stored as a numeric while the data from a csv is stored as an integer. I don't know why that won't let dplyr join on them while `merge` can or why it happens in the first place but I think this specific question is answered.

Comment: Just to be explicit, coercing the two dates using the same tool (e.g. lubridate) makes the join work perfectly. I landed here because I was bitten by the incompatibility between [data.table IDate and dplyr joins](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6230). Since the discussion here and there are both focused on the diagnosis and don't offer a treatment, I spent a little while thinking that the obvious solution of coercing to the same class may not be available...!

Answer (score 1):

I just had this exact same issue. Two data frames, each with a POSIXct date_time column and the dplyr join functions (by = "date_time") would not work due to incompatible types. Thanks to Matt Mills, I used the dput function to investigate the POSIXct columns and found that, even though both were POSIXct, one came out numeric and the other was character.

I fixed this by going back to where I created my POSIXct object and used this code:

```
df_temp <- df_temp %>% 
mutate(date_time = as.numeric(date_time)) %>% 
mutate(date_time = as.POSIXct(date_time, tz = tz_in, origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:00"))
```

Its weird...its like the POSIXct format remembers its original type. My added code forced the date_time fields in both variables to be numeric before converting to POSIXct.

dplyr::inner_join now works. Thanks for this thread; saved my bacon. ;)